# sp_describe_first_result_set is not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run this below query in `Sql Sever 2008`. But throws me error

> 'Could not find stored procedure 'sp_describe_first_result_set'

Any suggestion?

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set
N'SELECT * FROM mytable', NULL, 1
GO
```

Comment: Are you sure its SQL Server 2012? What do you get if you run `SELECT @@version`

Comment: Did you try with `Schema.sp_describe_first_result_set`?

Comment: I was surprised to know that version was sql server 2008 but when checked in About it was showing 2012. Thanks for the help.

Comment: IS there any way to figure out the column names from a sql select query?

Comment: Just for the record you are likely running SSMS 2012 but your actual SQL Server is 2008. These are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment you could insert some data into a temp table and then get the column info on the temp table and drop it.

```
SELECT *
INTO #SomeTempTable
FROM Blah

SELECT *
FROM   tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SomeTempTable')

DROP TABLE #SomeTempTable
```

Comment: This looks for the tablename in my case I need to get the columns that was in select query

Comment: What I am planning to do is create a new table and write a SP using cursor that imports all the rows from the existing table creating multiple rows for different transaction. Would that be a good solution though time consuming?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps you should post another question detailing exactly what you need. If you need just column information you could select your results into a temp table, run the query I provided above on that table, and then drop it.

Comment: @BVidhya I updated the answer to reflect my last comment.

Comment: Thank you SQLChao, I'll try your suggestion and will let you know